# Unknown column missing WHERE clause mysql command line

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an ssh layer. From that i'm going to get data via mysql shell. But when i use where clause inside a select function. it says bellow error message

```
echo $ssh->exec("mysql -ppass -u root xxxx -e 'select * from `student_master` where `SM_ID` =802350570V'");
```

This is says

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column '802350570V' in 'where clause'
```

What's the issue?

Comment: `802350570V` is a varchar datatype so you need to enclosed them with qoutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are passing your query as an argument so wrap query with`'`, but make sure that you add escape sequence to wrap query with`'`

You should use `"` to wrap column value which is not of type `int`.

Please try following:

```
`echo $ssh->exec("mysql -ppass -u root xxxx_col-b -e 'select * from student_master where SM_ID =\"802350570V\"'");`
```

Comment: @DrixsonOseña how do i put this as a variable 802350570V?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have single quote (`'`) in your `SM_ID = 802350570V'`. It should be like this:

```
echo $ssh->exec("mysql -ppass -u root esoftcar_col-b -e 'select * from `student_master` where `SM_ID` = \"802350570V\"'");
```

Comment: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: bash: student_master: command not found bash: SM_ID: command not found ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where = '802350570V'' at line 1

Comment: Do you have a table schema? What is the datatype of your `SM_ID`?

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column '802350570V' in 'where clause'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38593/discussion-between-samitha-and-christian-mark)